# Paypal standard not listed in opencart

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, opencart2.x

Paypal standard not listed in open cart. I have changed the currency. I have tried every possible way but i am not getting any solution . Is there any proper way to do it.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try to narrow down your question to what exactly do you need help with? Paypal standard? Opencart paypal module or something else? If possible please providing code if you have done some.

Answer (score 0):

Official PayPal OpenCart – Shopping Cart Setup Instructions here: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/opencart-setup

By any chance, after install PayPal, you haven't enabled it? (Status = Enabled)